# Assigning Buttons Inside An Outlet Collection Different Values (Swift 3 Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iboutletcollection

I am creating a quiz game and my quiz view controller has a label at the top with a question and then there are 4 buttons with text inside of them (1 of the 4 buttons contains the correct answer). I want to make it so that the buttons are in an outlet collection, however I am unsure how to make that outlet collection cycle through my array of answers and display the all 4 possible answers for each question. Would I use a loop? If statements maybe? If anyone could help me out here then that would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this:

```
//Outlet of the Collection of Buttons
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

//Outlet Collection of the labels
@IBOutlet var answers: [UILabel]!

//Action for once a button is pressed
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
for button in buttons{
button.hidden = true
   }

for answer in answers{
answer.hidden = false
   }
}

//Have the answers hidden by default 
viewDidLoad(){
for answers in answers{
answer.hidden = true
}
```